# Working backwards from window API's

Tags: debugging

My program often ends up at the kernel32.TerminateProcess API, now I've tried looking at the callstack in x32dbg but there's nothing. I've tried looking intermodular calls from my module and I've put a breakpoint on all of the calls, but yet it still ends up there.

I've also tried to look at all the intermodular calls to terminate process but they're are way too many, any tips to find it's origin?

Comment: Did you check the stack directly for possible return addresses? Sometimes the callstack cannot be retrieved properly.

Comment: There are no addresses on the stack, I dont know why

Comment: Is EIP perhaps set to an invalid memory location?

Comment: Uh yeah, that could be it

Comment: What's the actual issue you're having? This feels like an XY problem. Question could definitely use more detail and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems like you're having an exception which was thrown due to failure of access to a memory address. This might happen because of Access Violation or trying to access a non-existent address.

Here's [`TerminateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) syntax:

```
BOOL WINAPI TerminateProcess(
  _In_ HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_ UINT   uExitCode
);
```

Check for the *ExitCode* of the program to understand more what caused the failure:

> **uExitCode** [in]
>   The exit code to be used by the process and threads
>   terminated as a result of this call. Use the `GetExitCodeProcess`
>   function to retrieve a process's exit value. Use the `GetExitCodeThread`
>   function to retrieve a thread's exit value.

You should be able to find the exit code on the stack, or in the failure message.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Rohitab's API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). This will allow you to monitor every API call made by an application, and easily inspect parameters passed to each API (and the data returned). One of my favorite tools.

[image]